# Create JSON String - iOS

Tags: ios, json, string, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I have an iOS Application which makes a POST request to a server. In the body I have to add metadata in JSON format.

The JSON I have to send is this:

```
{
            "snippet": {
                "title": {VIDEO TITLE},
                "description": {VIDEO DESCRIPTION},
                "tags": [{TAGS LIST}],
                "categoryId": {YOUTUBE CATEGORY ID}
            },

            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": {
                    "public", "unlisted" OR "private"
                }
            }
         }
```

I have tried creating the JSON in a NSDictionary like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
NSDictionary *metadat = @{@"snippet" : @"{",
                                    @"title" : @"test_name",
                                    @"description": @"test_desc",
                                    @"tags": @"[test]",
                                    @"categoryId" : @"{1111}",
                                  @"}",

                                    @"status" : @"{",
                                        @"privacyStatus" : @"{",
                                            @"public",
                                        @"}",
                                    @"}",
                                  @"}"};
```

What am I doing wrong? I have followed the structure of the JSON format.

Thank you for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't add the `{` to the dictionary, but just add another NSDictionary.

But the example JSON is not really valid JSON, the `privacyStatus` seems a bit weird.

Something like:

```
NSDictionary *metadat = @{@"snippet" : @{
                                  @"title" : @"test_name",
                                  @"description": @"test_desc",
                                  @"tags": @[@"test"],
                                  @"categoryId" : @"{1111}",
                                  },
                          @"status" : @{
                                  @"privacyStatus" : @"public"
                                },
                          };
```

Comment: So you can nest a NSDictionary inside another NSDictionary?

Comment: Ofcourse why not? just as you can nest an array in an array/dictionary/

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you. Let me give this a try. This JSON block is actually begin sent to YouTube and they require "privacyStatus"...

Comment: No I don't mean that the node is weird, just the fast you can not have something like `"hello":{"name"}` in JSON. It should be `"hello":name"` or `"hello":{"key" : "value"}`